# Using created Java methods in a constructor

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I have created a method called fullPanel() that checks the amount of components in a JPanel, and if it is a certain number returns true. However, when I use this method in my class's constructor, I get error: cannot find symbol. I'm new to methods, so I'm not sure where I messed up, or if I created the method in the wrong place.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class Board extends JPanel {
  public boolean fullPanel(JPanel panel) {
    boolean full = false;
    Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
    if (components.length == 0) return full;
    full = true;
    return full;
  }

  public Board() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        if (selectedPanel.fullPanel() == true) {}
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message, which might/should include the name of the undefined symbol

Comment: please make sure that your code is correctly indented. I just did it for you, but the next time you should do it yourself. It helps readability and greatly improves the chance of your question getting answered.

Comment: `fullPanel()` method takes an `JPanel` as an argument. May be you trying to do `fullPanel(selectedPanel)`. You have not explained anything about your question and what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is `selectedPanel`? That's where the error is.

Comment: Thanks Shivam, that's what I needed. Sorry for the bad format and lack of the full error message, I'll include them in future questions.

Comment: @Femaref: how can you see indented code on SO?  Here on my machine, everything is always left aligned.

Comment: Dunno, never had any problems, on multiple OS and browsers. You need to indent with 4 spaces to get the `code` env. Maybe post on meta.so if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  public Board() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        if (fullPanel(selectedPanel)) {} // note removal of redundant "== true"
      }
    });
  }
```